# Audio Streaming Re-Recording Causing Echo

Tags: android, audio

I have an application on my android phone which records audio then sends it to my laptop then it will play out of its speakers (real time). However there is some problem.

I speak, the application streams it then the application records the voice that comes out of the speakers. I think this causes some "echo".

Does anyone have any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

It's called a feedback loop. The voice coming out of the speakers is again picked up by the microphone where it is retransmitted to the laptop again. The best solution is to isolate the microphone from the speakers or use headphones. If you've ever seen pictures of singers in the recording booth, you'll notice they are wearing headphones and this is the exact reason. Since you need to have the mic and speakers in the same room, maybe you could try using a mic with a pickup pattern that would be less sensitive in the direction of the speakers (e.g. cardiod pattern).

Another option that is much trickier is to employ some sort of [echo cancellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_suppression_and_cancellation). For example, on the recording side of things, you delay the recorded sound and mix an inverted version of it back in with the recorded signal.

```
              +---------------------------> mix------+
              |                              |       |
              +-- delay -- invert -- gain ---+       |
              |                                      |
              |                                      |
voice )))))) mic ((((((((((((((( speaker <-----------+
```

You then tweak the amount of delay and gain for your environment. One obvious problem is that a change in delay (such as relocating the speakers or microphone) will reintroduce the echo.

Any solutions more complicated than this and I would suggest looking for 3rd party software.

Comment: Hmm I need to use the microphone and speakers in the same room. Is there anyway be it using codes or other solutions to solve this? :/